# How to put text on an image with class

Tags: html, css, image, xhtml, styles

I want to put TEXT on IMG, but I can't change the code..

Any css will work

I have tried this but it is not working properly

```css
.n3 {
  position: relative;
}

.n4 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 7px;
  left: 12px;
  padding: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #FF0000, 0 0 5px #0000FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="n1" id="n1">
  <div class="n2">
    <a class="n3" href="URL">
      <span class="n4">TEXT</span>
    </a> <span class="n5"><a href="URL"><img class="n6" src="https://placehold.it/350x150"></a></span>
    <a class="n3" href="URL">
      <span class="n4">TEXT</span>
    </a> <span class="n5"><a href="URL"><img class="n6" src="https://placehold.it/350x150"></a></span>
    <a class="n3" href="URL">
      <span class="n4">TEXT</span>
    </a> <span class="n5"><a href="URL"><img class="n6" src="https://placehold.it/350x150"></a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does "Is not working properly" mean? What is the expected output?

Comment: Please fix the snippet I made to use the image size you need - the CSS works if the images are on a screen wider than their combined width

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you want is possible if you can't change the HTML and if you can't use JavaScript. I mean, the only way I could achieve your desired display is by cheating a little...

```css
.n3 {display:none;}

.n5 > a {position:relative;}

.n5 > a::after {
  position: absolute;
  content:'TEXT';
  bottom: 7px;
  left: 12px;
  padding: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #FF0000, 0 0 5px #0000FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="n1" id="n1">
  <div class="n2">
    <a class="n3" href="URL">
      <span class="n4">TEXT</span>
    </a>  <span class="n5"><a href="URL"><img class="n6" src="https://placehold.it/350x150"></a></span>
    <a class="n3" href="URL">
      <span class="n4">TEXT</span>
    </a>  <span class="n5"><a href="URL"><img class="n6" src="https://placehold.it/350x150"></a></span>
    <a class="n3" href="URL">
      <span class="n4">TEXT</span>
    </a>  <span class="n5"><a href="URL"><img class="n6" src="https://placehold.it/350x150"></a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```